# android service increment a variable in shared preferences

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I have a shared preferences, called "text", and I like to increment it by 1, when user press volume up, **even if the screen is locked**.
I asked and search too much and I found that this is possible by using Android services but because I'm new to android developing, I don't know how to do it exactly. I wrote a service but it's not work.
This my code for pressing volume keys.

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    myAndroidCounter();

                }
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    myAndroidCounter();

                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

The myAndroidCounter() method in above code, is a method that I wrote to increment the shared preferences variable by 1.

This myAndroidCounter() method:

```
int count = 0;
//call following method
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("incr", score++);
```

editor.commit();

Comment: post a code for myAndroidCounter

Answer (score 1):

you need to do following to increasement count in sharedpref

```
int count = 0;
//call following method
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("incr", score++);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: I know the trick but as I said I don't know how to do it when the screen is locked.

Comment: I wrote a service but I don't know am I do it write or not.Because I wrote my increment in on start, but my app has crashed and didn't run.
I think, should write it in on bind, isn't it?